# Showing non existent error in editor but still compiling fine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

Here is the error I see:

[image: screenshot]

Well, `LiveConcat` returns a `LiveConcatClass<T>` class:

```
public static LiveConcatClass<T> LiveConcat<T>(this IBindingList<T> first, IBindingList<T> second)
{
    return new LiveConcatClass<T>(first, second);
}
```

which inherits my `ReadOnlyBindingList<T>` abstract class:

```
public class LiveConcatClass<T> : ReadOnlyBindingList<T>
{
    //...
}
```

which in turn implements my `IBindingList<T>` interface (last one on the list):

```
public abstract class ReadOnlyBindingList<TResult> : IBindingList, IList, IEnumerable, IEnumerable<TResult>, ICollection, ICollection<TResult>, IBindingList<TResult>
{
    //...
}
```

And `LiveSelect` is an extension method that takes an `IBindingList<T>`:

```
public static LiveSelectClass<TSource, TResult> LiveSelect<TSource, TResult>(this IBindingList<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector)
{
    return new LiveSelectClass<TSource, TResult>(source, selector);
}
```

So I don't see why I'd get that error. The thing is, it compiles and runs fine, but cannot get rid of the error. I even trying restarting my machine. Could my VS installation be corrupt? I'm using VS 2012 Ultimate.

Comment: Try cleaning the solution and possibly wiping out the compiled `bin` directories.

Comment: I wonder if it is because you are call a non-extension method from the return type of an extension method?

Comment: You didn't post enough code to allow anybody to experiment with this.  Post your issue to connect.microsoft.com.  They'll need a small repro project that has this problem.  Use Microsoft Support if you don't want to wait.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Tried that and didn't fix it.

Comment: I believe this has to do with installing and uninstalling Resharper because after I uninstalled it, VS started doing all kind of weird things.